# Правильная сортировка и получение документов в MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, база-данных

В общем, столкнулся с такой проблемой: при получении доков, мне нужно отсортировать их по `_id` в порядке возрастания, и после взять определенное количество, начиная либо с начала массива, либо с конца. То есть, мне нужно получить все новые доки (которые имеют самые больше `_id`), в количестве `100` штук, или, например, самые старые в том же количестве, но лимитирование не берет в расчет сортировку, и отдает последние измененные доки. Можно ли как-то решить проблему средствами *MongoDB*, не прибегая к ручной фильтрации?

Comment: [SO:uses for mongodb ObjectId creation time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125521/uses-for-mongodb-objectid-creation-time)

    items.find.sort( [['_id', -1]] ) // get all items desc by created date.
    items.find.sort( [['_id', -1]] ).limit(30) // get last 30 createad items

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо, этот пример помог мне понять, какие именно берутся элементы при лимитировании)